# Is there are way to set the start frame for cvQueryFrame or cvGrabFrame?

Tags: c++, opencv

Using OpenCV (HighGUI.h), I have this code in main:

```
int frame_count = 0;  
while( (frame=cvQueryFrame(capture)) != NULL && (frame_count <= max_frame)) {
        //If the current frame is within the bouds min_frame and max_frame, write it to the new video, else do nothing
        if (frame_count >= min_frame){
            cvWriteFrame( writer, frame );
        }
        frame_count++;
    }
```

which queries capture for the frame, and only writes it if the frame is within the bounds min_frame and max_frame, both integers. The code works great, but it is not efficient enough for handling very large videos because it has to query capture for the frames leading up to min_frame, but it doesn't write them. I am wondering if there's a way I can just get cvQueryFrame to start at min_frame instead of having to work its way up to it. It already stops when it gets up to max_frame, since I moved

```
frame_count <= max_frame
```

into the while conditional. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you working with cameras or videos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the next frame to read by means of

```
cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, min_frame);
```

of course only for videos and not for cameras. The next frame read will be `min_frame` and the reading will go on normally from there (the frames after `min_frame` will be read) if you don't set the frame position again. So it's a perfect fit, as you just need to call it at the start.